# why this python code doesn't work, no output?

Tags: python-3.x

This python code should take a number and provide the list of digits present in it. But it gives no output.

```
b=[]
a=int(input())
while a>10:
    n=d%10
    b.append(n)
print(b)
```

Comment: your code is going in an infinite loop since you're not updating the value of `a` inside anywhere.

Comment: and `d` is undefined

Comment: solved inside the loop " a= a//10"